# Cache Timed Out or does not exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching, progress-db

I keep recieving the following error when attempting to submit to the server:

```
Cache timed out or does not exists.
StackTrace:
   at Royal4.MP.MasterScheduling.ProgramScheduling.iBtnAdd_Click(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnClick(ImageClickEventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain()
```

This Error shows up roughly after 2-3 minutes of usage and it seems like it is always happening on a postback that is doing some call to the server.  I would like to know what is causing this error (because it is happening quite often and it stops the updates from actually occuring).  Another note, when I run the code on my local machine, I cannot replicate the error, I only get the error on my production server.  Any help is appreciated.

**Additional Information:**
Langauge: C# .NET
Framework: .NET 1.1
IIS version: 6
Server: Windows 2003
Database: Progress 4GL (Don't ask)

If Additional information is required, just ask, I'll give as much information as i can.

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: You need tags that say '.net'. You need to tell us what you're talking to.

Answer (score 0):

"Cache timed out or does not exists." does not sound like a .NET error. My guess is it's being explicitly thrown by your code somewhere.

It would help to see the source code for the function at Royal4.MP.MasterScheduling.ProgramScheduling.iBtnAdd_Click, as it seems this is where the exception is being thrown.

Is your production environment a web farm? Often caching problems can come up under these environments (since cache is not shared between servers in a farm).

Comment: You are exactly correct!  The code it's self is throwing this exception.  But it brings up a new question.  This exception is being thrown when the cache is null.  Why would the cache become null after only a few minutes of idle time? (We have our IIS Timeout set to 5 minutes).  We, at first, thought it was due to the Application pool recycling, but when we set the Thresholds up high enough, the cache returns null before hitting the threshold, what else would make cache become null?

Thanks for your reply!

Tim